# How can I close the system menu of a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, systemmenu

I want to know Is the system menu (in the top-left corner of form) open? and if yes Close it.
How can I do it in .NET?

Comment: Can you modify the code of the form you want to close it's main menu?

Comment: Your process? Another process? Do you have the source code or is it not under your control?

Comment: Override with your own, then close it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615940/how-can-i-customize-the-system-menu-of-a-windows-form for further detail.

Comment: this issue is discussed in many pages like this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918264/how-i-could-cancel-opening-the-system-menu-of-an-application    but I want to Close this menu

Comment: MathuSum Mut, can you help me by code?

Comment: in Menu Functions I don't see a functions for close system menu : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You can call [EndMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647637.aspx) to *"end the calling thread's active menu"*.